# How can I use the draw in?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

could you explain to me the meaning of phrasal verb *draw in* in the context of arriving? In some dictionaries it is related to trains and railways. Can I use it with trams or something?

Comment: This question is unclear (to me). Please [edit] it to include some sample  sentences that use the phrase. Tell us what they mean, or what you think they mean or want them to mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the definitions from *Oxford Dictionaries*

- move somewhere in a slow steady way.
  "the train drew into the station"

You could say "The tram/bus drew up to the stop".

Comment: And Kate's second example shows that the idiom _draw in_ does not mean "arrive" but means something like "a large vehicle arrives inside somewhere".

Comment: @Colin Fine. **1. Drew/draw** can be used with smaller vehicle's  "The taxi drew up at the Ritz."**2. The second example would relate to a kerb-side stop** in the UK which would normally be outside in the UK. Inside would be at a station. Bus/tram/train station which is normally but not exclusively undercover, in fact with more modern Bus stations they are usually outside with the immediate area around a seating area local to, an individual vehicle's stopping position, being covered.

Comment: @Brad, I agree with all you say about _draw up_, but _draw in_ is not the same. A car, maybe even a bike can _draw up_ somewhere, but the only things I can think of that _draw in_ are trains and maybe ships. I wouldn't talk about a but _drawing into_ a terminal.